# Initialize array with closure, like { int idx -> new Item(idx) }

Tags: arrays, groovy

In Groovy, how to initialize an array with objects in compact form? I am fed up of making a for-i loop, there must be a Groovyer way?! ;-)

Here's some slightly different scenarios which would be great to cover:

Scenario 1:

```
Item[] items = new Item[x]
items.initialize { int idx -> new Item(idx) }
```

Scenario 2:

```
Item[] items = x.times { int idx -> new Item(idx) }
```

or..

```
Item[] items = arrayInit(x) { int idx -> new Item(idx) }
```

Scenario 3 - here we do not need the index:

```
Item[] items = x.times { new Item() }
```

(Must work with @CompileStatic, though - ref the x.times)

This actually work, but it would be great if there was something nicer:

```
Item[] items = new Items[x]
items.eachWithIndex { entry, int i -> items[i] = new Item(i) }
```

Comment: have you got chance to look at the solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the following class as `Item`:

```
@groovy.transform.ToString
class Item {
 def id
}
```

You can call it in one of the following two ways to produces **same output**

```
//You may change it as needed.
def x = 10
def items = (0..<x).collect { new Item(id:it) }

println items
```

**OR**

```
def items = (0..<x).inject([]){li,item -> li << new Item(id:item);li}
println items
```

**OR: If you want only array type and CompileStatic**

```
Item[] items = (0..<x).inject([]){li,item -> li << new Item(id:item);li} as Item[]
println items
```

Comment: `collect` is cleaner than `each`

Comment: and `0..<x` is cleaner than `0..x-1`

Comment: @tim_yates, thank you for your kind inputs, will make the changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Item[] items = new Item[x]
x.times { items[it] = new Item(it) }
```

Or how about this,

```
Item[] items = (0..<x).collect{new Item(it)} as Item[]
```

Comment: `0..<x` is cleaner than `0..x-1`

Comment: @tim_yates, Sure.